# Transpose rows to column, while flattening dataframe based on group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe...

```
idx Group      key     value  Time     IsTrue  
1   bicycle    person  yes    9:30      yes         
2   bicycle    name    bob    9:30      yes         
3   bicycle    alive   yes    9:30      yes            
5   non-cycle  person  no     1:30      no      
6   non-cycle  name    jack   1:30      no
```

And I want to the following result from the dataframe

```
idx Group       Time  IsTrue person name  alive
1   bicycle     9:30  yes    yes    bob   yes
2   non-cycle   1:30  no     no     jack  NA
```

Where the key columns become new columns and values are the rows for those new columns. All the others rows have the same always have the same values except for key and value columns. The keys change so I am going for something dynamic.

My current solution uses a pandas groupby & apply (based on the Group column), and creates a new dataframe for each group, but that seems way over engineered. Any simpler solutions to this?

Comment: Sorry Id is just the index, I’ll update that

Comment: You're right, I don't necessary need them after the transform

Comment: There is also issue at `IsTrue` values. Anyway, try my solution first to see if it is what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**edit**:
as you fixed output. I added another solution using `set_index` and `unstack`

```
df.set_index(['Group', 'Time', 'IsTrue', 'key'])['value'].unstack().reset_index()

Out[503]:
key      Group  Time IsTrue alive  name person
0      bicycle  9:30    yes   yes   bob    yes
1    non-cycle  1:30     no   NaN  jack     no
```

---

**Original:**
Your desired output is confusing. Let's try this solution if it is what you want. If it is not, I will delete it

```
df.pivot_table(index=['Group', 'Time', 'IsTrue'], columns='key', values='value', aggfunc='first').reset_index()

Out[487]:
key      Group  Time IsTrue alive  name person
0      bicycle  9:30    yes   yes   bob    yes
1    non-cycle  1:30     no   NaN  jack     no
```

Answer (score 1):

IN:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard()

pivot = df[['key', 'value', 'Group']].pivot(index='Group',columns='key').droplevel(0, axis=1).reset_index()
df.drop(['idx','key', 'value'], axis=1, inplace=True)

df = df.merge(pivot, on='Group').drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
```

OUT:

```
|   | Group     | Time | IsTrue | alive | name | person |
|---|-----------|------|--------|-------|------|--------|
| 0 | bicycle   | 9:30 | yes    | yes   | bob  | yes    |
| 1 | non-cycle | 1:30 | no     | NaN   | jack | no     |
```